# Cannot assign a value of type 'NSArray' to a value of type '[AnyObject]'

Tags: ios, swift

In swift, I have an `School` class, it has an `students` property of type `[AnyObject]!`

```
class School : NSObject {
  var students: [AnyObject]!
  ...
}
```

I got an instance of `School`, and an `NSArray` of string representing students' names. I want to assign this `NSArray` variable to `students`:

```
var school = School()
var studentArray : NSArray = getAllStudents()

//ERROR:Cannot assign a value of type 'NSArray' to a value of type '[AnyObject]'
school.students = studentArray
```

Why this error? Isn't array in swift compatible with NSArray in objective c??? How to get rid of above compiler error?

Comment: Using the actual type in the declaration allows the compiler to enforce assignments which is generally a "good thing".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your var `students` is a Swift array and expects object of type `AnyObject`, but you try assign it an `NSArray`. The two objects are not of the same type and it doesn't work.

But, given that `NSArray` is compatible with `[AnyObject]`, you can use simple typecasting to make the `NSArray` into a Swift array:

```
school.students = studentArray as [AnyObject]
```

Of course a better approach would be to stay in the Swift world and to forget NSArray altogether if possible, by making `getAllStudents` return a Swift array instead of an NSArray. Not only you will avoid having to do typecasts but you will also benefit from the power of the Swift collections.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like `school.students` is defined as Optional and might be nil therefore if you are sure that its not nil - unwrap it first by using !:

```
school.students as AnyObject! as NSArray
```

OR

```
school.students! as NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

My method written in object c which return NSMutableArray of type "Database"

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)AllRowFromTableName:(NSString *)tableName;
```

In swift i declare variable as

```
var petListArray: NSMutableArray = []
```

Save in model array as

```
 self.petListArray = self.dataBase.AllRowFromTableName("InsuranceTable")
```

Used in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 let tempDBObject = self.petListArray[indexPath.row] as! Database
 cell?.petName.text = tempDBObject.Hname
```

hope this help someone.